# How to retrieve parameter passed from ajax to controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to retrieve parameter passes from ajax in Controller in Codeigniter but did not know how to use it my ajax function is below

```
function sendVideoData(frm_id)
{

    var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("post_video_"+frm_id));

    // make the AJAX request
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"dashboard/do_upload",
        data: data+'&form_id='+frm_id,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data", 
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        },

    });

    return false;
}
</script>
```

I want to retrieve

> form_id

in my controller and use it

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple,

`echo $this->input->post('form_id')`

or simple php

`echo $_POST['form_id']`

inside your controller `dashboard` and method `do_upload`

You can get all list of post variables using `print_r($this->input->post())` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request can be:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard/do_upload",
        data: 'form_id=' + frm_id + '&data=' + data,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data", 
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
        },

    });
```

And in ur controller: `$this->input->post('form_id');`